# Typesafe-activator-eclipsified project has an endless list of dependencies in the scala ide

Tags: sbt, scala-ide, typesafe-activator

I have imported an typesafe-activator-eclipsified project into scala ide and I end up with an **endless list of dependencies/jars** in my ide which I find a little awkward to work with (see below).

Is there a way to **group all jars into one item** (e.g. sbt dependencies) using eclipse?

[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 1):

It depends of which view you have opened.

- If it is in the `Project Explorer` view, there is no way to collapse the list.

  But it is possible to hide the libraries. In the `Customize View` dialog, uncheck `Libraries from external`:

  [image]
- If it is in the `Package Explorer` view (which is a better view for Java/Scala projects), there is an option to collapse the referenced libraries, which is enabled by default:

  [image]